# Should the destructor for a base class that you won't use to delete an object, be virtual?

Tags: c++, destructor, multiple-inheritance, protected, virtual-destructor

Say I have two base classes,

```
struct A {}; 
struct B {};
```

and a derived one that uses **multiple inheritance**

```
struct D : A, B {};
```

If my use scenario goes something like this:

```
A *obj = new D;
```

i.e. I'll never use the `B` base class to refer to the derived object, **do I have to make the destructor of both bases virtual**? I'm currently declaring the destructor of `B` as `protected` to forbid other users from doing this, but is it enough?

What about the destructor of `D`?

Comment: No, but you should.

Comment: If you're never going to refer to `D` as a `B` you might be interested in [`protected` or `private` inheritance.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: To quote the mighty Scott Meyers: *...declare a virtual destructor in a
class if and only if that class contains at least one virtual function*.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Why? With `B`'s destructor being protected, you can't delete a `D` instance through `B*`, so in the example above only `A`'s destructor needs to be `virtual`

Comment: @RawN on the other hand, Herb Sutter says, "A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual."

Comment: @Brian so, when you combine the rules of thumb: If base class has virtual functions, then make the destructor public and virtual, otherwise make the destructor protected and nonvirtual.

Comment: @Praetorian for the reason Brian quotes. Any public non-virtual destructor is a maintenance risk. I wasn't sure from the wording of the question he was intent on keeping it protected.

Comment: Be careful with blindly applying any rule. For example, in Microsoft's COM technology, interface classes have virtual functions and no virtual destructor. It would be an error to try to delete a pointer to a COM interface.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Technically, that wouldn't be blindly applying a rule, but rather blindly assuming that others have followed the rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not necessary for `B`'s destructor to be virtual as long as a `B*` is never used to delete derived objects. See [expr.delete]/3:

> ... if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

In this case the "static type" is the type `T` *cv* where the operand to `delete` has type `T` *cv* `*`. So the requirements in your case are imposed on `A`, not on `B`.